# Saving space when saving a fitted gam object (mgcv::gam and scam::scam)

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am estimating a very simple model on a large dataset.  The formula looks like

```
 scam::scam(formula = ratio ~ s(rate,bs="mpi"))
```

These models are then used to generate predictions for new data.  I do not care about anything else about the model.

My problem is that the returned object is huge (a few GB), which tends to lead to problems downstream.

I believe this is due to the fact that scam and gam save the fitted values of each of the million of records.

Is there a way to only save a small object containing the minimum required to predict on new data?  This should not be bigger than a few kilobytes.

huge thanks!

**edit1**: here is a reproducible example to show my understanding of Gavin's answer:

```
library(mgcv)
data(iris)
library(tidyverse)
mydb <- iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa")

dim(mydb) # 50 records
model <-  mgcv::gam(formula = Sepal.Length ~ s(Sepal.Width,bs="cs"), 
                     data  = mydb)

print(object.size(model), units = "KB") # 78 KB

distinct_mydb <- mydb %>% distinct(Sepal.Width) # 16 distinct values for the independent variables
Xp <- predict(model, newdata= distinct_mydb, type = "lpmatrix")
coefs <- coef(model)
dim(Xp) # 16 records and 10 columns (one for each of the 10 knots of the spline?)
preds1 <- Xp %*% coefs %>% t()  
preds2 <- predict(model, newdata= distinct_mydb)  # preds 1 and preds2 are identical

print(object.size(Xp), units = "KB")   # 3.4 Kb
print(object.size(coefs), units = "KB") # 1.1 Kb
```

In this solution, I would save "Xp"  (3.4 Kb) and "coefs"  (1.1Kb) for a total of 4.5 Kb instead of saving "model" which takes up 78 Kb

What I am unsure is how I could use Xp and coefs next week to predict the Sepal.Length of a flower with a never-seen-before Sepal.Width of 2.5 ?

**edit2** : Is the answer simply to generate a grid of all possible Sepal.Width (rounded to some decimal) and just left_join this table with any future data?

```
fake_db <- data.frame(Sepal.Width = seq(0,max(mydb$Sepal.Width), by = 0.1))
fake_db$predicted_Sepal.Length = predict(model, newdata =  fake_db)
print(object.size(fake_db), units = "KB") # 4.3 Kb
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at `?mgav:::predict.gam` and the information for argument `type` and in particular `"lpmatrix"`.

For example you only need the coefficient vector and the output from

```
predict(model, newdata, type = "lpmatrix")`
```

where `newdata` is a much smaller subset of your original data but covering the ranges of the covariates.

This option `"lpmatrix"` is designed for use downstream or outside of R. The general idea is that given `"lpmatrix"` as `Xp` then `Xp %*% coef(model)` gives fitted values. But as you can reduce the size of `Xp` via `newdata` you can reduce the dimensionality of the object needed for prediction.

Comment: I've read a lot of your responses to this general question and I think I'm still missing something.  Is this correct?

`xp <- predict(original_model, newdata = original_data, type = 'lpmatrix')`
`coefs <- coef(model)`
`fitted_values <- xp %*% coefs %>% t()`

Using this pattern, how would I introduce a new batch of data to be scored?  Do I generate a new lpmatrix with every new batch, or is there a lpmatrix associated with the original training data that can be stored and applied to each subsequent batch of data?

Comment: Wait, I think I get it.  For each new batch of data you generate `Xp` using `predict()`, and then multiply that by `coefs` to get the scores.